# Make cell stay 10% wide

Tags: html, html-table, tablecell

I have a cell that is 10% wide with a couple words in it. When you shrink the window size, the size keeps getting smaller until it matches the length of the text inside and then it stops shrinking. I want it to stay at an exact 10% wide. How do I do this?

Sorry, working with divs is not an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might do the trick:

```
#your_table {
  table-layout: fixed;
}
```

Tables can (should, as it's up to browsers to implement this) have two types of layouts:

1. `table-layout: fixed`: This is the "stupid" table layout. The table doesn't care about its contents and just resizes carelessly.
2. `table-layout: auto`: This is the "smart" table layout. The table *cares* about it's contents and stops resizing cells once the minimum width and height of a cell is reached. This is default table behavior.

Thank you W3C: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/tables.html#propdef-table-layout

Answer (score 0):

It looks like what you really want is a set width. If you say that the table has to be 300px, you can specify that the cell is always 30px. The relative scale is what's causing the problem.

```
table.myClass{
    width: 300px;
}

table.myClass td.myOtherClass{
    width: 10%;
}
```